# (Excel) Sum with Index and Match or Vlookup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If you guys could help me it would be great.

so basically I have a spreadsheet of Daily SLA that needs # of Cases and Cases Processed added.
I couldnt figure out and I have searched google and youtube.

Column A just has the name of the Task (i.e. Logging voicemail SLA#1) because index/match doesnt work with merged cells.

[image]

I want the sum of each SLA at the bottom here. Originally I just added each cell but updates and more SLA were being added that editing them manually is time consuming =SUM(H18,H19,H20,H21,H22,H24,H92,H93,H94,H95).

the SLAs and Site (YYZ1, etc) are all scattered throughout the chart.
i.e. Logging voicemail SLA#1 are row 18-24 and 92-94 but are sorted by sites (YYZ1,YYZ2,etc)

[image]

If this is possible or if there is a better way, please let me know.

Much appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: not sure, but maybe [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) will do what you want

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do, but a PivotTable may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIF()` is the function you need here

Here is the formula I think you need:

```
=SUMIF(SLA_Name_List, SLA_Name_Lookup, Qty_of_Cases)
```

Where

- `SLA_Name_List` is Column A in your spreadsheet
- `SLA_Name_Lookup` is the SLA name you want to sum
- `Qty_of_Cases` is Column H in your spreadsheet

`SUMIF()` will add up the values in `Qty_of_Cases` for every row in `SLA_Name_List` that matches `SLA_Name_Lookup`

I used FormulaChop to generate this formula (Full Disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqLcU.png) is a screenshot of what the FormulaChop output looks like. [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07953150124148638939) is a link to the spreadsheet I made to test this.